# Sound cannot be played if the path is not C:/Windows/Media

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, wav

I would like to ask you about why the sound cannot be played if the path is not same as: `C:/Windows/Media/NameOfTheFile.wav`.

I have this function:

```
public class SystemManager
{
    static SoundPlayer _soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();

    public static void SoundEffect(string _soundLocation)
    {
        _soundPlayer.SoundLocation = _soundLocation;
        _soundPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemManager.SoundEffect("C:/Windows/Media/Savanna/Windows Exclamation.wav");
}
```

The above code did not work, the sound will not play.

But when I tried the below code, it does play.

```
void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemManager.SoundEffect("C:/Windows/Media/Windows Exclamation.wav");
}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure: In *both* cases, there was a file located at the path you specified, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a file located. You can check it on your computer sir, C Drive

Comment: Does it work when you use backslashes rather than forward slashes? Does it work when you create a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance for the file path and use its [`AbsoluteUri` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I have tried use backslashes, but it gives an error while trying to run the program, it says `Unrecognised escape sequence`

Comment: @Kaoru if you use backslashes you must ether change your string to `@"C:\Windows\Media\Savanna\Windows Exclamation.wav"` or `"C:\\Windows\\Media\\Savanna\\Windows Exclamation.wav"` as a backslash is a escape character, if you want to use it you must disable it with a `@` or use a double slash. (I deleted my old no-longer relevant comments)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Ooh yes, I forgot to include it, `_soundPlayer` is the name `SoundPlayer _soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer()`, and the sound did not play, but I did not get no error while trying to run the program, and also it does play on Windows Media Player when I play the sound from the specific folder `C:/Windows/Media/Savanna/Windows Exclamation.wav`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I have tried both of it, change the string path, `@"C:\Windows\Media\Savanna\Windows Exclamation.wav` and `"C:\\Windows\\Media\\Savanna\\Windows Exclamation.wav`, but the sound did not play also. Hmm, I think I just download new sound from the internet and include it in the project and load it, rather than keep thinking on how play the sound from that particular folder.

Comment: Hav u checked the file size of that file..?

Comment: Is the size of the file matter? Anyway, I already found a different way to play the sound. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the location - the problem is the sound file you are trying to play.  When I run the same code, I get the following exception:

> Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files.

The sounds in `C:/Windows/Media` are PCM, but the sounds in the subfolders are not.  You'll either need to find a way to convert them to PCM or find a different method of playing them.